# Comparing special characters with different encodings

Tags: perl, special-characters

I am parsing an HTML page, and I am comparing different characters to see if a certain page element is the one I want. I am getting the text of each element and I want to determine if the last character is a "–" long dash character. Here's what I have so far:

`$currentiterator` is the text I am working with.

```
if((substr $currentiterator, -1, 1) eq "–") {
    print "long dash found"; ## obviously I will do something different
}
```

However, this if statement never returns true. When I just print out the last character and it is an instance that contains the long dash, I get the question mark diamond thing (�
) and I had a feeling I would run into some encoding problems. What I am having trouble with is figuring out which component I should convert to what. What encoding do I need to convert the character I get as the `substring` to? I am assuming I would need to convert the "–" to the same encoding -- but how would I convert them?

Comment: Did you `use utf8`? Are you sure all character entities in the HTML are converted to their characters? Do [Unicode escape codes](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) work for the string (`\N{U+2013}` for –, `\N{U+2014}` for —)? Is your output stream properly encoded? Do you get a `wide character in print` warning otherwise?

Comment: what does `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper($currentiterator);` show (for the one that should match)

Comment: In the general case, with Unicode, you need to normalize before comparing. For example, `ä` can be represented as a precomposed single glyph, or as a lowercase `a` and a combining diaeresis. With multiple combining characters, you may need to change their order. There are multiple normalization algorithms for different scenarios. Google for NFC and NFD and friends.

Comment: Unicode support in Perl is a mess. Either read and reread until understood the `perldoc Unicode` or use e.g. Python which has saner Unicode support. The answer by dan1111 is basically the answer you are looking for: you haven't told Perl what encoding the input is, thus multi-byte long dash isn't treated by Perl as a single character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Encode](http://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) core module allows you to work with different character encodings in Perl.

Without knowing the design of your program, it's hard to say exactly what you need to do.

It could be that you haven't correctly set the encoding of your input.  Here are a couple of ways of doing that (all examples from the documentation; you need to figure out the correct encodings that you need):

Decode a string:

```
  $string = decode("iso-8859-1", $octets);
```

Open a filehandle with the appropriate encoding:

```
open(INPUT,  "< :encoding(shiftjis)", $infile)
    || die "Can't open < $infile for reading: $!";
```

However, it could also be that Perl isn't correctly reading utf-8 characters in your script.  As amon mentioned, you should [`use utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) to make sure that it will.

Finally, the incorrect display could be caused by the encoding of your standard output.  You can set your default input/output encoding like this:

```
use encoding "euc-jp";
```

However, even then it may be a function of your terminal being able to handle the encoding. Note that the output encoding by itself couldn't cause this problem.  It would only cause the character to not display correctly in your debug print message.